# How to use for loop in react native view

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop

I am new to react native. I want to that my single Icon button should call multiple function.
so how to use for loop in view in react native
here is my code

```
<View>
        <Icon onPress={this.requestCameraPermissionpan1} name="md-camera" size={30}/>
</View>
```

please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short sample code how to loop

```
   const tabs = [
    {
      title: 'Title 1',
      icon: 'arrow-up',
    },
    {
      title: 'Title 2',
      icon: 'arrow-down',
    },
  ];

{tabs.map((obj, index) => {
    return (
        <Button key={index} onPress={selectedTab.bind(this, index)}>
        <Icon
           size={20}
           name={obj.icon}
           color={index === item ? '#FF5E3A' : 'grey'}
         />
    </Button>
  );
})}
```

**For Example**

Just considering you have a `json` structure as `tab` variable for that
you can use `.map` and inside map make use `return` into which you can place your `component`. That should work fine.